# Search and replace full line in recursive files

Tags: grep, search, recursive, replace

I'm using:

```
grep -n -H -o -R -e textword .
```

List all file recursively under directory '.' with string 'textword' and show the file, line and only portion matching.

I need to remove lines that matched the text using a Linux command.

Comment: Did you look into `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -r -i "/textword/d" {} +
```

Remember that the search text is interpreted as a regexp by `sed` (with the `-r` option), so it might need escaping.

Use `sed -i.backup` to backup original files as `<filename>.backup`.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `find` and `sed` you could:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/^FIND$/d'
```